# How to add context references to a scenario programmatically

Tags: excel, vba, import, enterprise-architect, object-model

I'm currently modifying the importer script Simple VBA Excel to EA importer v4 from bellekens.

I have succesfully imported a usecase containing scenarios and scenario steps. I'm looking for a way to add the context references programmatically.

I'm currently adding them manualy with the use case Properties > Rules > Scenarios > Context References.

Is there a way to add theses context references from the API?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=4735.0

Basicly if you associate an actor with the use case it shows up in the context reference table.

to create the entry programmaticaly just add links between your Use case and actor programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote a [VBScript](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library/blob/4690b0a7e20245f342c54176bd8c6a426f12148a/Projects/Project%20A/Project%20Browser%20Group/Link%20with%20Domain%20Model.vbs) that does that. It looks into the logical class model and adds a context reference to it if that class name is used by the use case scenario step.

Here's that part that does the actual linking:

```
function linkDomainClassesWithUseCases(dictionary,regExp,usecases)
    Session.Output usecases.Count & " use cases found"
    dim usecase as EA.Element

    'loop de use cases
    for each usecase in usecases
        Repository.WriteOutput "Link to Logical Data Model", "Processing use case: " & usecase.Name, 0
        'first remove all automatic traces
        removeAllAutomaticTraces usecase
        'get all dependencies left
        dim dependencies
        set dependencies = getDependencies(usecase)
        dim scenario as EA.Scenario
        'loop scenarios
        for each scenario in usecase.Scenarios
            dim scenarioStep as EA.ScenarioStep
            for each scenarioStep in scenario.Steps
                'first remove any additional terms in the uses field
                scenarioStep.Uses = removeAddionalUses(dependencies, scenarioStep.Uses)
                dim matches
                set matches = regExp.Execute(scenarioStep.Name)
                dim classesToMatch 
                set classesToMatch = getClassesToMatchDictionary(matches, dictionary)
                dim classToMatch as EA.Element
                for each classToMatch in classesToMatch.Items
                    Session.Output "scenarioStep.Uses before " & scenarioStep.Uses
                    if not instr(scenarioStep.Uses,"LDM-" & classToMatch.Name) > 0 then
                        if len(scenarioStep.Uses) > 0 then 
                            'add a space if needed
                            scenarioStep.Uses = scenarioStep.Uses & " "
                        end if
                        'add the name of the class
                        scenarioStep.Uses = scenarioStep.Uses & "LDM-" & classToMatch.Name
                    end if
                    'create the dependency between the use case and the Logical Data Model class
                    linkElementsWithAutomaticTrace usecase, classToMatch
                    Session.Output "adding link between " & usecase.Name & " and Logical Data Model class " & classToMatch.Name & " because of step " & scenario.Name & "." & scenarioStep.Name
                next
                'save scenario step
                scenarioStep.Update
                scenario.Update
            next
        next
    next
end function

function linkElementsWithAutomaticTrace(sourceElement, TargetElement)
    dim trace as EA.Connector
    set trace = sourceElement.Connectors.AddNew("","trace")
    trace.Alias = "automatic"
    trace.SupplierID = TargetElement.ElementID
    trace.Update
end function
```